# Filter blog posts by month in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WordPress blog that currently displays all posts on one long page.

What I want is to have a widget or similar in the sidebar, which lists all the months of the year.

When the user selects a month (i.e July 2015), the page will then only display posts from that month.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: you should use `archive.php` in wp theme folder

Comment: Are you just wanting the sidebar to link to a page that shows only that month, or do you want the long page to filter out the selected month, like with jQuery or similar?

Comment: Yes instead of loading a long page of blog posts i want it to default to the current month and filter all blog posts according to the month they were written.